# In PHP MySQL query returns EVERY row. In MySQL Workbench, it works correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple PHP form:

```
<form action="listtenants.php" method="post">
    Search for Tenant: <input name="term" type="text" value="" /> 
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

At first I thought, the data was posting incorrectly; but after viewing the headers with LiveHTTP headers, it turns out it is posted correctly.

Here is my PHP script.  Like I said, the query works correctly in MySQL workbench; however in the PHP script, every row is returned.  Does anyone know why this could be?  Even echoing the posted variable returns the expected string.  Not sure what gives here.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 

$connect = mysql_connect("host","user","pass"); 
mysql_select_db("db", $connect);

$term = $_GET['term'];
$query = "SELECT itemid, first, last FROM tenants where CONCAT(first, last) LIKE '%$term%'";
$getUserid = mysql_query($query);

//$i = 0;
$records = mysql_num_rows($getUserid);

while($row_sections = mysql_fetch_array($getUserid))
{
    echo "$row_sections[0]    $row_sections[1]   $row_sections[2]";
    ?>
    <br><br>
    <?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really be using PDO or MySQLi instead of the old and unsecure mysql functions.

Comment: `echo $term` if it is empty every row is returned. You have to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` as specified on the form.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible query and highly dangerous.  BUT.. ..your issue is simple.
Your form submits via _POST, and your looking for variables using _GET.

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
```

will always be empty, so your query matches on `'%%'` - ie: everything!

Change it to:

```
$term = $_POST['term'];
```

..then go read about MySQL injections and follow the links in the comments to your post.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This will all be password protected; but, you do have a very good point.  I am just trying to get things working, without worrying about nuances.  After I get it working correctly, I'll implement PDO.  I'm just not terribly familiar with PHP and I'm taking it one step at a time.

Comment: Also, I did some looking around and I guess I still don't under stand the relationship between POST and GET.  My understanding is that if the form POSTS and the action points to a PHP script, in the said PHP script, wouldn't you set a variable by GETting the posted data?

Comment: @theCowardlyFrench Nope!  If a form submission method is _POST, then the submitted form data is accessed from the global _POST array.  If a form submission method is _GET, then the submitted form data is accessed from the global _GET array.  The main difference between the 2 methods is that _GET variables are visible in the URL, so insecure.  _POST variables are not, so are more secure. eg:  _GET for pagination, _POST for login.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  It's a real satisfying feeling when you finally have something explained to you in a way that makes it click.  $_POST vs $_GET has been nagging me ever since I started, I never really understood the nuances of each.